# replace nth pattern in vim with given string

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file with this format:

```
field1     | field2         | field3    | field4    | field5    | field6     | field7
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
```

I want to replace the 2nd CSV column (field4) with 0;0;0;0;0 in vim. I tried

```
/|\s\+\(\d\+;\)\+
```

to see if i could match but as soon as i add the last `\+` it matches the whole line so i won't be able to replace it. I also tried with `\{1\}` in hopes it would repeat the pattern once and then i could `\(\)` the same pattern again, but my vim doesn't seem to like `{}` (RHEL 5.5 vim 7.0.237).

I'll take sed, awk or perl but i'd really like to get a better grip on wim's regexes.

Comment: Why in vim and not using `awk`?

Comment: @anubhava As per the original post, i'd really like to get a better grip on vim's regexes, saves me the time of getting out of vim (being picky, i know). In the meantime i did post an awk answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This replaces the 4th column (delimited by |) with** `0;0;0;0;0`

```
%s/^\([^|]\+|\)\{3\}\zs[^|]\+/ 0;0;0;0;0 /
```

**Before**

```
field1     | field2         | field3    | field4    | field5    | field6     | field7
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
alpha      | beta           | anything  | 1;2;3;4;5 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
a | b | c | d | e | f | g
```

**After**

```
field1     | field2         | field3    | 0;0;0;0;0 | field5    | field6     | field7
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 0;0;0;0;0 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
alpha      | beta           | anything  | 0;0;0;0;0 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
a | b | c | 0;0;0;0;0 | e | f |
```

**Explaination**

The substitution pattern skips the first three fields delimited by `|` and replaces the forth

- `%s` performs substitution on every line in the file
- `^` matches the beginning of the line
- `[^|]\+|` matches everything that isn't a `|` plus a trailing `|`
- `\(...\)\{3\}` matches three occurances of whatever `...` is
- `\zs` denotes the beginning of the match used for substitution
- `[^|]` matches everything up to the next `|`

Answer (score 0):

Using awk i did this:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { 
    FS="|";
    OFS="|";
}

{    
    for(i = 1; i < NF; i++) {
        if(i == 4) {
            printf "2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0";
        } else {
            printf "%s", $i;
        }
        printf OFS;
    }
    printf RS;
}

END { 
}
```

I wanted to use vim, but i'll use whichever tool is best for the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in `vim` then use:

```
:%s/\v(\|\s*\d+(;\d+)*\s*\|\s*)\d+(;\d+)*/\12;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0/
```

However I would strongly recommend using `awk` for this job due to processing of rows and columns. Your suggested awk command can also be improved by using:

```
awk -F ' *\\| *' -v OFS=' | ' 'NR>1{$4 = "2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0" } 1' file

field1     | field2         | field3    | field4    | field5    | field6     | field7
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
irrelevant | doesn't matter | 1;2;3;4;5 | 2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0 | 1;2;3;4;5 | don't care | whatever
```

Comment: Iused awk, i'll try both answers when i'm back at work, thanks.